# Font icon ligatures

Tags: html, css, icon-fonts

I made my font icon set with fontello. At the moment it works like this:

```
<div class="icons_class home" ng-click="toHome()"></div>
```

and the CSS of the corresponding class is:

```
.icons_class {
   font-family: 'myFont';
   ...
   ...
}
.home:before {
   content: '/e822';
}
```

but I want to use like this:

`<div class="icons_class" ng-click="toHome()">home</div>`

like material icon.

Is it possible? Do I have to use ligatures for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it.

Instead of fontello.com I must use icomoon.io, where there is a specific feature for ligatures:

> Ligatures
>
> To enable/disable ligatures, press the fi button in the font tab of the app. By enabling ligatures, you will be able to assign words/tags to each glyph. (use comma to assign multiple words to each glyph.)
>
> If the platform in which you use your font supports ligatures, typing the words you assign to each glyph would bring up that glyph. Ligatures are not supported in IE 9 and older, but the IcoMoon app provides a javascript polyfill for you. IE 10 and other modern browsers support ligatures.